# Let $A \rightarrow B$ be etale. Is multiplication $B \rightarrow B \otimes_A B$ faithfully flat?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, etale-cohomology

Let $A \rightarrow B$ be an etale ring morphism.

We have that the map, via base changing by $-\otimes_AB$
$$ B \rightarrow B \otimes_A B$$
It is etale, hence smooth hence flat.

> Is this map *faithfully* flat?

---

My thoughts are applying [10.38.16, Stacks Project](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00H9).
It suffices to show that the induced map on Spec is surjective. I could briefly recall that

> A) $B\otimes_AB \simeq B \times B'$ from etale property with multiplication $B\otimes_AB \rightarrow B$ coinciding with projection. ( I don't know why)

Combined with.

> B)  Given two rings $R_1, R_2$, if $P$ is prime ideal in $R_1$, then $P\times R_2$ is prime ideal in product. Indeed, if $(a,b)(c,d)=(ac,bd) \in P\times R_2$, $a$ or $c$ is in $P$.

We deduce that the map is faithfully flat.

Comment: Multiplication is a ring homomorphism $B \otimes_A B \to B$. The homomorphism $B \to B \otimes_A B$ you refer to is not multiplication but rather $b \mapsto b \otimes 1$. Geometrically speaking this is projection on a factor. This is a split monomorphism (compose it with multiplication!), and you know it is flat, so it is a fortiori faithfully flat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X = \operatorname{Spec} A$ and $Y = \operatorname{Spec} B$. The map you are interested in is the projection $p_1 : Y \times_X Y \to Y$ onto the first factor. As you point out, it suffices to check that this map on $\operatorname{Spec}$ is surjective.

Indeed, we see it is surjective, by observing that $p_1 \Delta = \mathrm{id}_Y$, where $\Delta : Y \to Y\times_X Y$ is the diagonal, induced from the multiplication map $B\otimes_A B \to B$.